# Where does mutation engine resides in Metamorphic \polymorphic viruses?

Tags: virus

I was reading about Metamorphic & polymorphic viruses ..

to what i understood ; they both uses mutation engines  to avoid detection by anti-viruses, as the polymorphic encrypts\decrypts its code , and the metamorphic generates a logical equivalent code.

According to what i know , viruses are parasitic  male-ware. i.e. it needs a host to produce copies of itself and cannot act independently like worms .

So my question is , during the virus's typical life cycle (infection - duplications- activating payload- etc   )  , where is the mutation engine in all this ? And when a virus moves from its host to another PC what happens to the engine ? And what happens at the next host in the first cycle , how can it achieve its mutation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mutation engine is contained in the virus body.

It is just another module of the virus. Viruses typically have a file scanning module, an infection module, a mutation module, a payload module and many others. On infection, the mutation module is used to mutate all of its modules and pass them to the infected host.

Mutation engines are mostly targeted by antivirus engines because they have typical behavior and are often used for multiple families of infector malware. They are targeted also because they are weekly mutated. That is because "mutating" the "mutator" can lead to bad "monster mutations" :)

Comment: LOL "i like the monster mutation stuff :) " ..
Thanks for the answer , but didn't we beat the whole point ?
I mean , now the AV is hunting for the engine instead of the virus's signature ,  aren't we back to square zero again ??

Comment: The mutation engine is part of the virus so from the AV point of view it **is** the virus. Most modern malware is hidden behind a layer of encryption so AV is targeting the decryption routines. A lot of packers, cryptors and protectors are detected by AV instead of the real malware payload. 

Some AVs look at the overall behavior of the binary file but by the time it was allowed to run in order to be observed, it may be already too late.

Comment: Can you please recommend a good resource/textbook to read more about this topic ?

Comment: There has also been indications of server-side mutations recently.

http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/07/31/server-side-polymorphism-malware/
http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Teaching/466-566/2012/Resources/presentations/2012/news-stories/AndroidMalware.pdf

Comment: I have my knowledge from working in the antivirus industry so it's hard to recommend a textbook for this constantly changing subject.

Here are resources addressing polymorphic malware in abstract and in particular.
http://goo.gl/1PGTI
http://goo.gl/01I0n
http://goo.gl/5bp3a
http://goo.gl/NbLgD
http://goo.gl/HHFe3
http://goo.gl/tSc4r
http://goo.gl/gD3yR
http://goo.gl/VWhWO
http://goo.gl/e6vYM
http://goo.gl/sD1lO
http://goo.gl/N64oi

Slides:
http://goo.gl/4DNTA
http://goo.gl/cHT6G
http://goo.gl/XWsgU
http://goo.gl/YO8jS

Practical:
http://goo.gl/oq3Gy
http://goo.gl/xvaw5
http://goo.gl/TEC2c

Answer (score 1):

I think things become a little more complex...As today every hosts hold sufficiently memory to let a big, very big virus install without making a big print on host's memory: While a server could work normally with 24Gb memory how mutch could use a virus before it will be statistically visible?

There is now enough space to hold a full C compiler, analytic engines and lot of *packages*, like upgrade engines (same as apt-get could do in Debian, for sample). Installed virus may now be upgraded to follow anti-virus developments and have appropriate reaction...

I think, (but don't have any proof ;), that new generation of polymorphic viruses could grown and become *self-versonized* by himself... (and maybe through some hidden repositories for *authoritative* upgrades).

Nota: Bandwidth are growing too, so with the help of a little of stegano (another package in virus installation) making upgrade could be strongly hidden too.

But... I'm (a little) paranoid and have a lot of imagination.

Comment: I think the scenario ur speaking about is closer to worms than viruses ....viruses are parasitic malware so on the same host you will find a copy in each infected file , so they cant start updating or they will be detected because the unusual traffic (imaging all the infected files are updating on a host)

Comment: Maintening registers like dns and use local connections whenever exists, clearly **yes**! Don't think hackers are stupids! If a good programmer team could build impressive so called *intuitive OS*, why did you think a *good* pirate team could not invent new generation of intuitive and evolutive viruses? (At all, a virus don't need to *infect* all files nor many, depending on how, why and what, only 1 file by host is sufficient)